# Reconnect automatically to a disconnected ssh session

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys, ssh-agent, ssh-keygen

I am new to this community ,
I am working on my iot project in which my microcontroller is working as a server, taking data and executing request. My client is end device (mobile,tablet) and I am connecting through SSH.

The problem appears if suddenly my internet gets off - the ssh session breaks off, and again I have to reconfigure it using this command:

```
ssh -o TCPKeepAlive=yes -R 80:192.145.47.33:80 example@ssh.localhost.run
```

And in  a similar manner if the power of the server (microcontroller) gets trip off, then I get the similar situation.
I want that session get automatically configured without manual intervention.

Answer (score 6):

[AutoSSH](https://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) is the tool you want to use for this. It starts the SSH connection and restarts it in case it breaks up.

Comment: And on top of that I would suggest using tmux or screen in your session so that you can recover your original shell when you reconnect.